# Spring boot OAuth2 sample

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a Spring-Boot application with MongoDB. I want to register the client using OAuth2.0 strategy and store client-id and client secret key in database. I am able to generate the access token by using some dummy client and secret key from the below url: http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

I want to know how to generate the client id and secret key in my java code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to generate client id and secret key from access token? Client id and secret key used to obtain the access token. So this is probably what you need indeed (correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: Yes, I need my java code to generate the client id and secret key which will be used to get access token.

Comment: You can't just generate clientID and secret. Or better to say that you can, but since your Authorization Server is not aware of it - they would not have any sense. You need to register your Client in Authorization Server first.

Comment: Can you share some examples or url on how to do it. I am unable to find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Client ID and secret are generated by service providers to let the developers register their application and access their API's.

There are many ways of generating Client_id and Client secret.It  depends on your choice.

Client_id is a public identifier for apps.It should be **unique** and **not easily guessable** . So you could use like **a 32-character hex string , Guid , Guid + systemTime ,also you can hash it , encrypt it** or anything else you want to make it unique identifier. (you would find java code easily for the same)

Client_secret is a secret known only to the application and the
authorization server.So you could use **a cryptographically-secure library to generate a 256-bit value and converting it to a hexadecimal representation.**
You should avoid using common UUID libraries.

Also you should not store the secret in plain text, instead only store an encrypted or hashed version, to help reduce the likelihood of the secret leaking.

Here are some examples of client ID from services that support Oauth:

Foursquare: ZYDPLLBWSK3MVQJSIYRF1OR2JXCY0X2C5UJ2QAR2MAAIT5Q

Github: 6779ef20e75817b79602

Google: 292085223830.apps.googleusercontent.com

Instagram: f2a1ed52710d4533bde25be6da03b6e3